# apalike bibtex bibliography styles

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

How to cite Russian article on russian language using apelike style?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\lib.bib}
@Book{Tovarovskiy2015,
 author    = {Товаровский, И.Г.},
 title     = {Познание процессов и развитие технологии доменной плавки},
 publisher = {Журфонд},
 year      = {2015},
 address   = {Днепропетровск},
 pages     = {911},
 lang      = {ru}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\cite{Tovarovskiy2015}
\bibliography{lib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try using `bibtexu` instead of `bibtex`

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! What you are doing is essentially correct (minor changes `\lib.bib` -> `lib.bib` and move the loading of `fontenc` to before `babel`), but latex complains about the first initial in your reference, that it is an `Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`.  So first try replacing this with a different character, and then try reentering the character.  If the problem persists, ask about how to use this code point.

Comment: `apalike` is a bibliography style with hard-coded English strings (like "and", "et al." etc.) If you write your document in Russian, you may want to choose a style that speaks Russian.

Comment: It's `apalike`, not `apelike`...